# Is it possible to identify multiple links using <a> tag in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink

I have 2 links inside a class `link_div` like this.

```
<div class="link_div">
 <a id="upload_link" href='' >Upload File</a>
 <a id="search_link" href='' >Search File </a>
</div>
```

My requirement is on clicking each link a `div` will be displayed.The displayed div contents will be almost same except small changes.So I thought to write code like this:

```
$(".link_div a").click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert($(".link_div a").attr('id'));
                    $("._new_filesharing_div").show();
                    return false;
                });
```

My idea is getting the id of the clicked link and using the if loop to check which link is clicked and thereby adding a button for `upload`  on clicking `upload file link` and adding a button for `search` on clicking `search file link`.Rest of the contents are almost same.

Here I always get the clicked `Id` of the link as `upload_link` eventhough the user clicks the other link.I think jquery is taking the id of the first  tag. May I know is it possible to get the ID of the clicked links or I should write code for each link seperately

Comment: Please **at least** complete the basic tutorials (http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/) before rushing here to ask questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the event handler, the clicked element is `this` (more specifically, the element on which you bound, which can be a parent of the really clicked element).

Change

```
alert($(".link_div a").attr('id'));
```

to

```
alert(this.id);
```

**Note :** Don't create a jQuery object just to get a standard property of a DOM object. Not only is `$(this).attr('id')` slow, it's also less readable and that wrapping is just totally useless.

Comment: Or, $(this).attr('id')

Comment: `this.id` is more efficient

Comment: @C-link How is it useful to create a jQuery object to get the id of an element ?

Comment: both method is same but the difference is only js and jquery way and the faster vs slower not?

Comment: The "jquery way" *calls* the js way. This just adds some unnecessary code and function calls.

Comment: man ... `this.id` takes two steps, which is faster then using `$(this).attr('id')`. [See what happens](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes/attr.js#L26) when you use the `.attr()` method...

Comment: @C-link when you're doing `$(this).attr("id")` you're basically saying: "I don't know anything about the DOM API so instead I'm going to wrap my perfectly fine object that has an id property with a jQuery selection set, then treat it like one and query its attributes for the id as a string and return that. It's not just slower and longer to write, it's awful. Please consider reading more about the DOM API.

Answer (score 0):

`$(".link_div a")` will return you all the `a` tags in `.link_div` and `attr` will return the `id` of the first element of that set.So your code is not working. The preferred way to achieve your goal in this scenario is by using :

```
this.id
```

It will return you the clicked link as jQuery sets event callback functions ***context*** to the element which ***triggered*** the event.

But if you need the jquery object in the later part of your code. You can sort it in this way:

```
var aTag = $(this);
aTag.data('blaKey','blaValue');
```

Comment: Why are you duplicating my answer ?

Comment: @dystroy your first answer was not having any explanation.

Comment: @MD.SahibBinMahboob yeah, I agree on return clicked link.... but I was pointing useless with destroy...

Comment: -1 for `$(this).attr("id")` which is an anti pattern. Let your APIs work for you not vice versa.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum thanks. Updated answer accordingly

Comment: You're still giving it as your first option and it's still an anti pattern, when you suggest it - people use it, it's a very bad practice.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum makes sense. Updated again :)